# Why should I use a modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This question has always bothered me. Why do people sometimes present view controllers as modal view controllers? Can't you always just push a view controller onto the navigation controller and pop it later? It seems way more straightforward and consistent. I've seen people using the two interchangeably and it just ends up driving me nuts.

Are there any specific cases where it would be better to present a view controller as a modal view controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) describes its uses well.

> Modal view controllers provide interesting ways to manage the flow of
>   your application. *Most commonly, applications use modal view
>   controllers as a temporary interruption in order to obtain key
>   information from the user.*

And

> There are several reasons to use modal view controllers in your
>   application:
>
> - Use them to gather information from the user immediately.
> - Use them to present some content temporarily.
> - Use them to change work modes temporarily.
> - Use them to implement alternate interfaces for different device
>     orientations.
> - Use them to present a new view hierarchy with a specific type of
>     animated transition (or no transition).

Answer (score 5):

Typically, navigation controllers store immediately (or when the back button is pressed), while modal view controllers can have both a cancel and a save button.

The mail compose view is a good example of this.

Answer (score 1):

As Joe pointed out, Apple's documentation provides a pretty good overview for using modal view controllers in your app. I suspect that you are thinking about this too much from a programming perspective and not enough from a user perspective, though. Sometimes examples serve to illustrate the point further, so consider the following example.

On the iPhone, the default interaction mode in Mail is one of viewing. Navigation between mailboxes, threads, and messages within this mode is handled by animating transitions between views from the left and right edges of the screen (popping and pushing view controllers). This provides the user with much needed visual context as they are traversing the hierarchy of their email messages.

Since composing a new message is not part of the viewing interaction, it doesn't make sense to animate that view in from the right. The user isn't navigating to a new message, they are creating a new message. Since this is a different interaction, the interface is presented modally. The same is true of moving messages between mailboxes - this too is done modally. These modal views provide visual cues to the user that the way in which they are interacting with the app has changed.